# Sqlite Increment column value based on previous row's value

Tags: sqlite

How do I increment a column value based on previous column value in Sqlite? I need to do this for 1000+ rows. I have data in the first row say 100. I need to increment the next 1000 rows by 2.

```
Row#  ColName
1       100
2       102
3       104
4       106
```

I tried something like this:
Update Table SET ColName = (Select max(ColName ) from Table ) + 2 but this puts 102 in all columns.

Comment: 102 in all rows is what I would have expected from your description. Show some example rows before/after.

Comment: @CL The post got edited with an example. I need to do this in SqliteStudio.

Comment: Is there an actual column like `Row#`?

Comment: @CL Nope that was only for illustration. I don't have an integer column to get the prev row data. The only other columns are text and Guid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this table has a [rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), it is possible to count how many previous rows there are:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ColName = (SELECT MAX(ColName)
               FROM MyTable
              ) +
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM MyTable AS Previous
               WHERE Previous.rowid < MyTable.rowid
              ) * 2
WHERE ColName IS NULL
```

Comment: This helped a great deal. I had trouble with how the data was arranged but I made some omodifications to this query in order to make it work for my needs. Your help is MUCH appreciated.