# SQLite: How to update rows with a sequence of numbers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

In SQLIte I would like to renumber the values in a specific column with a sequence of numbers.
For example the relevance-column in these rows:

```
relevance | value
-------------------
3         | value1
5         | valueb
8         | valuex
9         | valueaa
```

must be updated starting from 1 with increment 1:

```
relevance | value
-------------------
1         | value1
2         | valueb
3         | valuex
4         | valueaa
```

What I'm looking for, is something like this:

```
-- first set all to startvalue
UPDATE MyTable SET relevance = 0; 
-- then renumber:
UPDATE MyTable SET relevance = (some function to increase by 1 to the previous row);
```

I tried this, but its not increasing, seems like Max is not evaluating on each row:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET relevance = (SELECT Max(relevance ))+1;
```

Comment: Just found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834181/sqlite-increment-column-value-based-on-previous-rows-value?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a temporary table where you will insert the column `relevance` from your table and with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function another column with the new sequence and then update from this temporary table:

```
drop table if exists temp.tmp;

create temporary table tmp as 
select relevance, row_number() over (order by relevance) rn
from MyTable;

update MyTable
set relevance = (
  select rn from temp.tmp
  where temp.tmp.relevance = MyTable.relevance
);

drop table temp.tmp;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4uAZsntdTVXyqXmt77voAD/0).

Comment: Thank you, it works. 
MyTable has already rowid,so this one is also working:
`update MyTable
set relevance = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM MyTable AS Previous
                              WHERE Previous.rowid < MyTable.rowid)+1; `

Comment: Rowid is not guranteed to provide the correct results. If you deleted any rows and added new rows rowid may be reused.

Comment: Ok, good point.there is a Id-column in the table as well with AUTOINCRMENT. Using this one now

Comment: Future readers, you can use a CTE instead of temp table. See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4uAZsntdTVXyqXmt77voAD/1).